# Using multiple client-id+secret with one instance of traefik forward auth

Tags: devops, traefik

https://github.com/thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth/issues/44 mentions a single tfa implementation of multiple client-id+secret.

Does anybody know where the documentation to do so can be found?

I followed several documentations

- https://brianturchyn.net/traefik-forwardauth-support-with-keycloak/
- https://geek-cookbook.funkypenguin.co.nz/docker-swarm/traefik-forward-auth/keycloak/
- https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/

But found nothing on the multi client use case. I would be eager to read about it.